# Selecting hidden form element by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to set a value to a hidden form element by selecting their Id and not their name attribute. The hidden element has `id="user_lat` and `name="user_lat"`. How can I do that?

I seem to be able to select by name:

```
$("input[name='user_lat']").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
```

MY attempt at selecting by id below does not work:

```
$("input #user_lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the id is to be applied to the input, the selector can have no spaces:

```
$("input#user_lat").doSomething();
```

If you place a space between `input` and `#user_lat`, the selector attempts to match a child of the input, which doesn't make much sense. It would be like having the following markup:

```
<input><el id="user_lat" /></input>
```

Removing the space matches any input that contains the ID:

```
<input id="user_lat" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You must stick them together `"input#user_lat"`

`input #user_lat` means:
Look for an `input` and then find inside the element with id `user_lat`

Answer (score 2):

You are close, take out "input" from the second statement and you should be good.

```
$("#user_lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are usign the selector "input #user_lat" your saying the element "user_lat" inside an input. So what you need to do is just delete the space between them, something like this:

```
$("input#user_lat") ...
```